# Undefined reference to 'function' -- Linker issue?

Tags: c++, linker

I am currently trying to compile and link my C++ files on a linux terminal. The command I run is:

```
g++ -o gameplay gamePlay.cpp player.cpp main.cpp display.cpp -lcurses
```

The command seems to compile everything perfectly, but once it trys to link things I get 2 errors.

```
undefined reference to 'gamePlay::deal(std::vector<card, std::allocator<card> >, std::vector<player, std::alloator<player> >)'

undefined reference to 'gamePlay::score(player)'
```

Below is my gamePlay.CPP file. I am really lost and any help would be much appreciated!

```
#include "gamePlay.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>

int gamePlay::compareCenter(int leadplayer){
int highest = center[leadplayer].getCardNum();
if(center[leadplayer].getCardNum() == 1)
    highest = center[leadplayer].getCardNum() + 13;
int suit = center[leadplayer].getSuit();
int player = leadplayer;

for(int i = leadplayer+1; i < leadplayer+4; i++)
{
    if((suit != 1) && (center[i%4].getSuit() == 1))
    {
       player = i%4;
       suit = 1;
       highest = center[i%4].getCardNum();
    }
    else if(suit == center[i%4].getSuit())
        if(center[i].getCardNum() == 1){
            player = i % 4;
            highest = center[i].getCardNum() + 13;
        }
        if(highest < center[i%4].getCardNum())
        {
            player = i%4;
            highest = center[i%4].getCardNum();
        }

}
players.at(player).setTricksTaken(players.at(player).getTricksTaken()+1);
return player;
}

vector <card> createDeck() {
//Create the Deck and create each suit by calling define cards.
vector <card> deck;
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j <= 13; j++){
        card newCard (i,j);
        deck.push_back(newCard);
    }
}
random_shuffle (deck.begin(), deck.end());
return deck;
}

void gamePlay::deal(vector <card> &deck, vector <player> players){
for(int j = 0; j<4; j++){
    for(int i = 0; i<13; i++){
    players.at(j).addCard(deck.at(0));
    deck.erase(deck.begin());
    }
}
}

bool containSuit(card lead, player players){
bool suit = false;
for(int i = 0; i < players.getHand().size(); i++){
    if(lead.getSuit() == players.getHand().at(i).getSuit())
        suit = true;
}
return suit;
}

bool gamePlay::onlySpade(player play){
for(int i = 0; i<play.getHand().size(); i++){
    if(play.getHand().at(i).getSuit()!=1)
    return false;
}
return true;
}

int gamePlay::handCheck(int xevent, int yevent, vector <player> players, int     trickStart){
        for(int i = 1; i < 14; i++){
            if(xevent<(i*6) && yevent>17 && yevent<23 &&      players.at(0).getHand().at(i-1).getSuit() != 0 && players.at(0).getHand().at(i-  1).getCardNum() != 0){
                card playedCard = players.at(0).getHand().at(i-1);
                //first check to find card on display
                //check to see if leading or not
                //if leading use spadesBroken function
                //if not leading use contains suit function
                if(trickStart==0 && !getSpadesBroken()){
                    if(onlySpade(players.at(0)))
                        return i;
                    else if(playedCard.getSuit() != 1)
                        return i;
                    else
                        return NULL;
                }
                if(trickStart == 0 && getSpadesBroken())
                    return i;
                if(trickStart > 0 &&  containSuit(center[trickStart],players.at(0))){
                        if(playedCard.getSuit()==center[trickStart].getSuit())
                        return i;
                }
                if(trickStart > 0 &&    !containSuit(center[trickStart],players.at(0)))
                    return i;
                else
                    return NULL;
            }
        }
}

void gamePlay::displayHand(){
int offset = 0;
    for(int i =0; i<players.at(0).getHand().size(); i++){
        monitor.displayCard(offset, 18,     players.at(0).getHand().at(i).getSuit(), players.at(0).getHand().at(i).getCardNum(), 0);
        offset+=6;
    }
}
void gamePlay::humanPlay(int trickStart){
    int xevent, yevent;
    int key = monitor.captureInput();
    for(;;){
        mvprintw(8,26,"Please choose a card to play.");
        // if a mouse event occurred
        if (key == -1) {
            xevent = monitor.getMouseEventX();
            yevent = monitor.getMouseEventY();
            int handCh = handCheck(xevent, yevent, players,    trickStart);
            if(handCh != NULL){
                card played = players.at(0).getHand().at(handCh-1);
                players.at(0).getHand().at(handCh-1).setCardNum(0);
                players.at(0).getHand().at(handCh-1).setSuit(0);
                center[0]= played;
                monitor.displayCard(34, 11, center[0].getSuit(),   center[0].getCardNum(), 0);
                displayHand();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
void gamePlay::CPUplay(int trickStart, int CPU){
    bool goodCard = false;
    card playedCard =players.at(CPU).getHand().at(0);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < players.at(CPU).getHand().size(); i++){
             playedCard = players.at(CPU).getHand().at(i);
                //check to see if leading or not
                //if leading use spadesBroken function
                //if not leading use contains suit function
                if(trickStart==CPU && !getSpadesBroken()){
                    if(onlySpade(players.at(CPU)))
                        break;
                    if(playedCard.getSuit()!=1)
                        break;
                }
                if(trickStart == CPU && getSpadesBroken())
                    break;
                if(trickStart != CPU &&   containSuit(center[trickStart], players.at(CPU))){
                        if(playedCard.getSuit()==center[trickStart].getSuit())
                        break;
                }
                if(trickStart != CPU &&   !containSuit(center[trickStart], players.at(CPU)))
                    break;
    }
                players.at(CPU).getHand().at(i).setCardNum(0);
                players.at(CPU).getHand().at(i).setSuit(0);
                center[CPU]= playedCard;
                if(CPU==1)
                monitor.displayCard(29, 7, center[CPU].getSuit(),  center[CPU].getCardNum(), 0);
                if(CPU==2)
                monitor.displayCard(39, 2, center[CPU].getSuit(), center[CPU].getCardNum(), 0);
                if(CPU==3)
                monitor.displayCard(49, 7, center[CPU].getSuit(), center[CPU].getCardNum(), 0);
}


void gamePlay::score(player play){

int trickOver = play.getBid()-play.getTricksTaken(); // Calculate the difference   between bid and actually taken.

//Bidding Double Nil (if gets it 200 points other wise -200 points)
if(play.getDoubleNil()){
    if(play.getTricksTaken()==0) //player did get Double Nil successfully
        play.setScore(play.getScore()+200); // add 200 points
    else
        play.setScore(play.getScore()-200);
}
if(play.getBid()==0){ //Bidding Nil (if gets it 100 points other wise -100 points)
    if(play.getTricksTaken()==0) //player did get Nil successfully
        play.setScore(play.getScore()+100); //add 100 points
    else //player didnt get Nil
        play.setScore(play.getScore()-100); //take away 100 points
}
if(trickOver>0){ //player bids more than number of tricks won
    play.setScore((trickOver*-10));  //decrease score by 10 poitns for every   overtrick
}
if(trickOver<0){ //player bids less then number of tricks won
    play.setSandBag(play.getSandBag() + 1); //increase sandbag by 1
    play.setScore((trickOver*(-1))+(10*(play.getBid()))); //increase 10 points   per trick bid on and 1 point per trick over
}
if(play.getSandBag()>10){ //check for sandbagging
    play.setScore(play.getScore()-100);
}
play.setBid(NULL); //reset players bid to NULL
play.setDoubleNil(false); //Player has not yet bid double NILL.
}

void gamePlay::runGame(){

for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){ //Creates 4 players with hands included
    player play;
    players.push_back(play);
}

int count = 0;
int handStart = 0;
while(players.at(0).getScore()<500 || players.at(1).getScore()<500 ||   players.at(2).getScore()<500 || players.at(3).getScore()<500)
{
    int xevent;
    int yevent;
    for(;;){
        mvprintw(3,2,"Click here to bid Double Nil or type out your bid   now.");
        int key = monitor.captureInput();
        monitor.drawBox(7, 4, 3, 2, 0);
        monitor.drawBox(7, 4, 3, 2, 0);
        if (key == -1) {
            xevent = monitor.getMouseEventX();
            yevent = monitor.getMouseEventY();
            break;
        }
        if (key > 0){
        stringstream messageString;
        messageString.str("");
        messageString << "Your bid is now: " << key;
        monitor.bannerBottom(messageString.str());
        players.at(0).setBid(key);
        break;
        }
    }
    if((xevent>=7 && xevent<=10)&&(yevent>=4 && yevent <=6)){
        players.at(0).setDoubleNil(true);
    }

    vector <card> deck = createDeck();

    deal(deck, players);
    displayHand();
    int trickStart = handStart;
    int count = 0;
    while(count<13){
    switch (trickStart)
    {
    case 0: humanPlay(trickStart);
            CPUplay(trickStart,1);
            CPUplay(trickStart,2);
            CPUplay(trickStart,3);
    case 1: CPUplay(trickStart,3);
            humanPlay(trickStart);
            CPUplay(trickStart,1);
            CPUplay(trickStart,2);
    case 2: CPUplay(trickStart,2);
            CPUplay(trickStart,3);
            humanPlay(trickStart);
            CPUplay(trickStart,1);
    case 3: CPUplay(trickStart,1);
            CPUplay(trickStart,2);
            CPUplay(trickStart,3);
            humanPlay(trickStart);
    }
    trickStart = compareCenter(trickStart);
    }
    for(int n =0; n<4;n++)
        score(players.at(n));

    handStart = (handStart +1) % 4;
}
}
```

Also here is my card.h file as well

```
using namespace std;

class card { //Create cards for deck
int cardSuit;
int cardNum;
public:

    int getSuit() {return cardSuit;}
    int getCardNum() {return cardNum;}
    void setSuit(int a){ cardSuit = a;}
    void setCardNum(int a){cardNum = a;}
    card (int suit, int number){cardSuit = suit; cardNum = number;}
    card (void){cardSuit = 0; cardNum= 0;}
};
```

Comment: Thank you for understanding the difference between compilation and linking. Please fix your code indentation, though.

Comment: Seems that the declarations in gameplay.h have no matching definitions in gameplay.cpp. Post the h file too so it is easier to see.

Comment: I have a similar problem and solved by
a) defining the C function before the C++ method definition that was using it.
b) prefixing :: to the references to the C function in C++ code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've defined a freestanding function

```
void deal(vector <card> &deck, vector <player> players){
for(int j = 0; j<4; j++){
    for(int i = 0; i<13; i++){
    players.at(j).addCard(deck.at(0));
    deck.erase(deck.begin());
    }
}
}
```

whereas I suppose you meant to define the member function `gameplay::deal`

```
void gameplay::deal(vector <card> &deck, vector <player> players){
//...   
}
```

As jmp correctly noticed in the comment, the same is true for your `score` function.

Also, I'd pass `players` by reference, since you seem to invoke addCard() on the players which means (I suppose) that you need the passed parameter to be altered.

Comment: This worked perfectly for my code, but I have this one last pesky error that I don't understand. After attempting to link and compile, I get the following error.    ./ccEKgSTO.o: In function `gamePlay::gamePlay()':
> main.cpp:(.text._ZN8gamePlayC1Ev[gamePlay::gamePlay()]+0x7b): undefined reference to `card::card()'

Comment: @PeterBlum: Have you provided the definition (implementation) for the card class's constructor?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan I put my .h file above. I didn't think I needed to create a .cpp file for the card. Does the last line of the .h not define the default constructor?

Comment: @PeterBlum: The default constructor is implicitly defined only if you don't declare it (or any other constructor) explicitly. And you have two explicitly declared constructors, so the default one will not be implicitly defined

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Well I am confused as to why I am getting the error then. I defined the constructor for when I do not define any parameters for it, and I also defined it for when it is created with parameters.

Comment: @PeterBlum: In your .h file, you defined nothing except for the class itself. You *declared* two constructors. They should also be defined (in the .cpp file if they are not inline and in the .h file if they are inline)